# How To Package PyPI Packages And Import Them?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I am trying to package up a PyPI package into a single file containing all of the source for that module and its dependencies. Is there an **automated** way of doing this? Is there a way to download a package and all of its dependencies in a format that can be shared, and then can be imported again by another program directly from that file?

I have already tried to use pip's "download" command, but its results are inconsistent and I could never find a way to import it. I tried downloading everything and placing it into a zip, but it wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes and no. You can try a [*wheelhouse*](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/repeatable-installs/#using-a-wheelhouse-aka-installation-bundles). In principle it is possible for Python to import directly from a zip file. Off the top of my head I do not know of an automated way of doing it that would exactly fit your expectations, but probably there is some tool somewhere that fits. -- You better fix your question to show exactly what your tried with `pip download` and why you say that it wouldn't work.